# Why were all but one answer deleted on this question?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

@rumtscho deleted all but one answer on this question: [Is there some "trick" to be able to eat jalapenos without getting an "upset stomach"?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/116836/is-there-some-trick-to-be-able-to-eat-jalapenos-without-getting-an-upset-stom/116847#116847)

Why?  None of the other answers look like spam, or are completely off-topic.  Was this an error?

Answer (score 4):

We have always stayed away from medical advice and answers that are offering a diagnosis or home remedies fall flatly into the “off topic, medical advice” category.

The question per se is borderline and can be interpreted differently. Some physiological effects can be influenced by cooking and preparation methods (e.g. beans and gas), and questions like that are within our scope. Up to now, we have kept the jalapeño question in that vein, waiting for answers that mitigate the problem with kitchen methods.

However, answers that offer medical advice, diagnosis or rely on supplements are answers in the off topic realm and therefore get removed. If the incoming answers keep going in a medical direction, we must conclude that the question is perceived as asking for medical advice and reassess whether we can keep it open.

Comment: Given that three of the answers were related to health problems, then, I'd argue that's the case.  Otherwise, by hiding all but one of the answers, you're de facto supporting a diagnosis that there IS NOT a health problem, and isn't that just as problematic?

Comment: No, it’s not implying anything. We simply stay away from _any_ kind of diagnosis or assumption. I would be fine with a comment recommending that the OP talks to their GP. Anything beyond that is not our area of expertise

Comment: Posted, given that I really think the OP is describing a medical problem that could get worse if they continue to mess around.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this should be a comment, as I don't come to meta often, but I just saw this question again after however long, and... I don't really get why my answer was deleted. I suggested trying other varieties of peppers, stated I have an allergy, and offered a relatively low-risk way to figure out whether or not a given food would provoke the same response.

I had all of 2 votes, so I'm not particularly invested anyway, but I don't understand how making a recommendation based on my experience counts as making a diagnosis or offering medical advice.

Some of the comments I left? I get it. But the answer, especially scrubbed of any subtext added by the comments doesn't offer a diagnosis. I just say I have a food allergy... So how do I interpret this deletion? I was making a diagnosis by having an allergy myself? I was giving medical advice by suggesting direct substitution of an offensive food? Or was it recommending caution because I don't know what caused the initial reaction...?

I mean, if I had said op's most likely allergic and needs to carry an epi pen, THAT would have been medical advice. But as is I'm still  just kind of confused, because I don't know how I broke the rules here.